# The type or namespace name 'Label' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi i got this error in the morning, and i don't know why or what is producing it
 Somebody told i must use Android.App to be able to use ActivityAttribute class and thouse properties but i'm already using it.
I understand that error CS0246 it's for reference, i tried to remove and readd the refrence with out success and the error perssist.
thank you for your help.

Error :

> CS0246 - The type or namespace name 'Label' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

[image]

this is my code

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DatePickerService.Droid {
  [Activity(Label = "DatePickerService", Icon = "@drawable/calen", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
  public class MainActivity: global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
      TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
      ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

      base.OnCreate(bundle);

      global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
      LoadApplication(new App());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Appears you are indeed missing a reference or using wrong framework...

Comment: Which reference did you remove/re-add? From the doco, looks like you need Mono.Android.

Comment: The reference to the main solution

Comment: What happens if you add a reference to Mono.Android?

Comment: i'm already using Mono.Android v=0.0.0.0 the required one, but i tried i adding  >Mono.Android.Export1.0.6723.32796  but still the same, i turn back to v=0.0.0.0

Comment: Do you have Mono.Android (0.0.0.0) referenced? (see Requirements) https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.ActivityAttribute

Comment: yes i have it in my refrences :s